# Error Parsing XML for android:drawable

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Hi 
I am facing a problem
I want my application to pick up resources from the framework. Here is my code snippet of an xml.

For this to be achieved following changes were made in attrs.xml

and themes.xml at the framework level

@android:drawable/btn_minus_ss

The drawable btn_minus_ss.png is added to drawable-hdpi folder at the location framework/base/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi
Whenever I open the application, it crashes.
I get the following error in logs

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3701): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #5:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

However, when I use this
android:background="?android:attr/theme_btn_minus_ss"
I don't get any error. I want to use 
android:drawable
What is the cause and how can this problem be solved.

Thanks & Regards
Aviral

Answer (score 4):

The error

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3701): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #5: tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

has to do with the format of your xml, you are setting something like

```
<item android:background="@foo-value-here" />
```

What the error is telling you is that it should be like this

```
<item android:drawable="@foo-value-here" />
```

Answer (score 3):

i think i had the same problem, it seems to be a bug in the android eclipse-plugin. the solution is the same as for this question (close eclipse and restart it): [android include tag - invalid layout reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533972/android-include-tag-invalid-layout-refernce)

Answer (score 1):

Also make android:drawable the first attribute of item tag - it worked for me.