# Can't change selected item's background color in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to set different color to selected item on Navigation Drawer and here's my code

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_text"
    />
```

**drawer_list_lesector.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/light_pink_color" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/light_pink_color"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/light_pink_color"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/light_pink_color"/>
    <item android:state_active="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/light_pink_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
 </selector>
```

**light_grey_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F1F1F1"/>
</shape>
```

**light_pink_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F1E1F1"/>
</shape>
```

and **nav_item_text.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#BBBBBB" />
</selector>
```

but it's still doesn't change selected item's color

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same issue and finally got to the bottom of it.

In the menu definition file `@menu/activity_main_drawer` you need to add `android:checkable="true"` to each item that you want to be checkable or the `itemBackground` will not see the checked state.

Don't ask me why `itemIconTint` and `itemTextColor` work just fine without this but `itemBackground` needs it, makes no sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Sash_KP Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886453/change-the-color-of-a-checked-menu-item-in-a-navigation-drawer/31074133#31074133)

Well you can achieve this using [Color State Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html). If you notice inside your `NavigationView` you're using

```
app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
app:itemTextColor="@color/primary_text"
```

Here instead of using `@color/black` or `@color/primary_test`, use a `Color State List Resource`. For that, first create a new `xml` (e.g drawer_item.xml) inside `color` directory (which should be inside `res` directory.) If you don't have a directory named `color` already, create one.

Now inside `drawer_item.xml` do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="checked state color" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="your default color" />
</selector>
```

Final step would be to change your `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_navigationview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"  // notice here
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item" // and here
    app:itemBackground="@color/drawer_item"// and here for changing the background color of the item which is checked
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer">
```

Like this you can use separate Color State List Resources for `IconTint`, `ItemTextColor`, `ItemBackground`.

Now when you set an item as checked (either in `xml` or programmatically), the particular item will have different color than the unchecked ones.

[image: According to your work]

Comment: I wrote this code using those answers but it still not working, I don't know maybe I forgot something

Comment: what you want? according to your work ... it's like that...see gif

Comment: yes, I want something like this but I'm getting this exception

Comment: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Comment: you need to take these drawable in drawable folder

Comment: your code work fine ? take these drawable like drawer_list_lesector.xml,light_grey_color and light_pink_color to res/drawable folder

Comment: they are in drawable folder

Comment: See this answer... I don't know it's work but try to switch like that in drawable.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114322/error-item-tag-requires-a-drawable-attribute-or-child-tag-defining-a-drawa/13047898#13047898

Comment: still nothing :/ it's working on pressed but not when it's selected

Comment: See also this it's answer

Comment: update your studio than http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-7

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_list_selector"
```

to:

```
app:itemBackground="@color/drawer_list_selector"
```

move the file `drawer_list_selector.xml` from `/drawable/` folder to the `/color/` folder (create one if it doesn't exist).
now, change the `drawer_list_selector` to be a selector of **colors**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#F1E1F1" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#F1E1F1"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#F1E1F1"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#F1E1F1"/>
    <item android:state_active="true" android:color="#F1E1F1"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
 </selector>
```

Comment: dear sir.... it 's giving an error.... Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/drawer_list_lesector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0b0059 Binary Xml error with navigation...

Comment: when I tried this this exception occurred "Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable "

Comment: @Arjunsaini it's "drawer_list_selector", not "drawer_list_lesector".

Comment: @misha make sure you've put the selector in the color/ folder, not the drawable/ folder

Comment: I had in drawable but then I moved to color but changed code as you wrote but this exception occurred

Comment: @marmor sir ya in my code i am saving with this name....so in logcat drawer_list_lesector

Comment: according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5295522/819355 it might be that the selector you reference must be a drawable-selector, not a color-selector, in that case, you can change back to your starting code, just change the default state from android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" to a shape with a color