# Can't use color statelist in navigationVIew Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, statelistdrawable

I have two project one uses color statelist selector in NavigationView to change the background color of items in Navigation Drawer on different state of interactions.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/nav_bgstate_list"  <------ 
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_state_list"  <------
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_state_list"  <------
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"  />

        These three lines causes error but when I remove them, it works fine.
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Item checked -->
        <item android:color="@color/brand" android:state_checked="true" />
        <!-- Item pressed -->
        <item android:color="@color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
        <!-- Item default -->
        <item android:color="@color/brand70" />
    </selector>
```

I copied the same code into another project and it started throwing bunch of errors. The log is below

```
    2021-06-09 07:49:13.564 12895-12895/ca.company.project.betaversion E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: ca.company.project.betaversion, PID: 12895
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.company.project.betaversion/ca.company.project.betaversion.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at ca.company.project.betaversion.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:57)
            at ca.company.project.betaversion.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:51)
            at ca.company.project.betaversion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:111)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable ca.company.project.betaversion:color/nav_bgstate_list with resource ID #0x7f0600d9
         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/nav_bgstate_list.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0600d9
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:820)
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:630)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:877)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:819)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
            at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:147)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
    2021-06-09 07:49:13.569 12895-12895/ca.company.project.betaversion E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
            at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:83)
            at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:196)
            at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
            at ca.company.project.betaversion.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:57)
            at ca.company.project.betaversion.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:51)
            at ca.company.project.betaversion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:111)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
         Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:189)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
            at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:807)
                ... 36 more
```

I checked minSdk version, compilied sdk version, themes, gradle version, dependencies with their versions etc. and everything is same, nothing is different. I know I should be using drawable states instead of color state but I don't understand why it is working in other project but in the another one.

**Edit 1**

I found out that the crash was happening because of I set the itembackground with color state selector. itemIconTint and itemTextColor works fine with color state selectors. Only itemBackground crashes whenever I try to set the state selector there so I found one solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61071246/2118039), basically I need to add checked  `android:checkable="true"` but even after adding this it crashed. I don't know why.

**Edit 2**

So I realized color state selector is working on newer version of android > 10 but not on the older version of android.

Comment: You can try using drawable selector, that worked for me

Comment: @ZeusAlmighty I have already mentioned that in my post that I can use drawable selector but I don't want to, why? Color states are simple and easy to make, whereas to make drawable selector, I would have to create drawable and set color in them which is just one more extra step with bunch of extra files. Color selector just need state selector file whereas in drawable selector you need one file to make selector and multiple files to make drawable states.