# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity in andorid app deployment

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to deploy my app in android playstore and getting the below error. My splashscreen is defined in its usual place. But still getting this below error.
i added multiple size images in my drawable folder as well but its not working.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lazypeacock.rokkhakorta/com.lazypeacock.rokkhakorta.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040001
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040001
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2974)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.v()
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.p()
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.a()
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.u()
   at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.onCreate()
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
   ... 11 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:161)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
   ... 20 more
```

andoridmanifest.xml:

```
    package="com.lazypeacock.rokkhakorta">
   <application
        android:label="rokkhakortafinal"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                       <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
             </activity>
       </manifest>
```

Comment: That seems to be the relevant part: `Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114322/error-item-tag-requires-a-drawable-attribute-or-child-tag-defining-a-drawa)

Comment: Share your xml file.

Comment: Sorry but it is not.

Comment: @PriyankaRajput  <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />

Comment: Mainly error is in your drawable xml file, Please share that file's code

Comment: Are you sure you have `launch_background.xml` under res/drawable folder?