# Using custom title bar on select activitys within an app

Tags: android, android-layout, titlebar

Ok i will try to be as detailed as i can here.  I have an app with multiple activities in it.  Some of the activities I want to have a custom title bar on with an Image, then text, then image button navigating back to the home(aka main activity).  Most of the pages i want the custom title bar on are list view pages.  I have successively been able to load the custom title bar but it doesn't load any text field or images just the title bar with nothing in it.  here is the code that i've used.

window_title.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:background="#660000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon72" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.39"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingRight="5dip" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#660000"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

custom_style.xml

```
     <resources>
<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#660000</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

Classes.Java

```
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.Window;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 public class Classes extends ListActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

        setListAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ministries, list));

        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or where i need to make changes but I would like to be able to have this custom title bar on some of the activities and load the name of that activity in the title bar.  I've looked at several tutorials and these two have helped but i'm kinda stuck a bit.  http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/android-dynamic-and-custom-title-bars/
and this one has helped the most and what i basicly followed
http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

Thank you for any help you can give. I would have posted pics but haven't gotten that far on here yet so thank you again for any help

edit 
[image: This is what i want it to look like]
[image: this is what it looks like now in app]

the top image is what i want the title bar to look like and the bottom is what it looks like in app

Comment: do you have a layout for your costume title bar

Comment: yes that is the window_title.xml file i posted

Comment: it loads the title bar in the activity, just none of the content of the title bar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310780/1107317  refer this link i have given one answer hope this will help

Comment: i think we are on the right path here but getting some errors on the code that goes in the activity.  Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
  EnumHeaderName.   thats on the public void line of the code you refered me to

Comment: can u paste the lines of code that giving you the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use include tag of android to add your window_title.xml....

Refer : 
[android include tag - invalid layout reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533972/android-include-tag-invalid-layout-refernce)
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html