# Include directive is not been including the required content

Tags: java, android, include

Hi I'm very new to android programming and I'm playing with the `include` tag.

I have a layout named `companylogo` as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- Logo Start-->
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and other layout file named `homepage` which looks as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff">
        <include layout="@layout/companylogo"  />
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But this doesn't adding the image to the `homepage` layout.

I even tried adding `android:layoutwidth/height` tag. Not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your `homepage` layout

Comment: if there was voting for names , +1 , :) :) :)

Comment: what android version are you testing on?

Comment: Actually, your layout works on 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0 (tested). Check your drawable. Try to make new empty project with this layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when we are implementing xml into our code,then to show the effect of the layout we have to clean project some times.

and also try to add both layout_width and layout_height attribute into include tag.

Tried cleaning the project and if it still didn't work then

Closed Eclipse, and just opened it again, and that worked.

for more information check this link:

[android include tag - invalid layout reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533972/android-include-tag-invalid-layout-reference)

[Does Android XML Layout's 'include' Tag Really Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631614/does-android-xml-layouts-include-tag-really-work)

Answer (score 0):

now try once again with this :

```
<include layout="@layout/companylogo"  
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```