# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133

Tags: android, out-of-memory, inflate-exception

I am programming a mobile commerce app for a company. There is an error in while showing product details in an activity. These are details:

`package com.Troyateck.sucukevim;`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Product extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
ImageButton sepet,sepeteekle;
String id,mail,ad;
TextView greeting;
public String urunid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Mert");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        ad=extras.getString("ad");
        urunid=extras.getString("urunid");
        System.out.println(ad);
        greeting=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.greetingsText); 
        greeting.setText("Hoşgeldiniz, "+extras.getString("ad"));
    }
    GetProductsData get = new GetProductsData();
    try {
        icerik=get.execute(new String[] { urunid }).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(icerik.size()>1)
    {
        icerik.remove(icerik.size()-1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < icerik.size(); i++) {
        try {
            LoadContents(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Kontroller();
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText("Şuanda sepetinizde "+Cart.userCart.size()+" ürün bulunmaktadır.    \n Sepetinize gitmek için tıklayınız");
}
public ArrayList<ProductIcerik> icerik = new ArrayList<ProductIcerik>();
private void Kontroller() {

    sepet =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    sepeteekle =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

    sepet.setOnClickListener(this);
    sepeteekle.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.imageButton1:
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton2:
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Class.forName("com.Troyateck.sucukevim.Cart"));
             intent.putExtra("ad",ad);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hata : " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }   
        break;
    case R.id.imageButton3:
        //that's
        Cart c = new Cart();
        System.out.println(c.userCart.size());
        System.out.println("job1");
        c.AddToCart(icerik.get(0).id,icerik.get(0).baslik,"1",icerik.get(0).link,icerik.get(0).fiyat,icerik.get(0).kisaca);
        System.out.println(c.userCart.size());
        TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText("Şuanda sepetinizde "+Cart.userCart.size()+" ürün bulunmaktadır. \n Sepetinize gitmek için tıklayınız");
        break;
    }
    }
public void LoadContents(int i) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
    ImageView resim = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    resim.setImageDrawable(LoadImageFromWeb(icerik.get(i).resim));

    TextView baslik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtbaslik);
    baslik.setText(icerik.get(i).baslik);

    TextView fiyat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtfiyat);
    fiyat.setText(icerik.get(i).fiyat+" TL");

    TextView aciklama = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtaciklama);
    aciklama.setText(Html.fromHtml(icerik.get(i).detay));

    TextView stoka = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtstok);
    if(icerik.get(i).stok=="1")
    {
        stoka.setText("Stok Durumu: Stokta Var");
    }
    else if(icerik.get(i).stok=="0")
    {
        stoka.setText("Stok Durumu: Stokta Yok");   
    }
}
public Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url)
{
    try
    {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    return d;
    }catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exc="+e.getMessage());
    return null;
    }
}
public class ProductIcerik 
{
    public ProductIcerik() 
    {

    }

    public ProductIcerik(int id,String link,String baslik,String fiyat,String kategori,String birim,String indirim,String stok,String etiket,String detay,String resim) 
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.link=link;
        this.baslik=baslik;
        this.fiyat=fiyat;
        this.kategori=kategori;
        this.birim=birim;
        this.indirim=indirim;
        this.stok=stok;
        this.etiket=etiket;
        this.detay=detay;
        this.resim=resim;

    }



    public int id;
    public String link;
    public String baslik;
    public String fiyat;
    public String kategori;
    public String kisaca;
    public String birim;
    public String indirim;
    public String stok;
    public String etiket;
    public String detay;
    public String resim;
    public String anasayfa;
    public String secilmis;
    public String yeni;
    public String satis;
}
private class GetProductsData extends AsyncTask<String,  ArrayList<ProductIcerik>, ArrayList<ProductIcerik>> {

    @Override
    protected  ArrayList<ProductIcerik> doInBackground(String... params) {
         URL url;
         ArrayList<ProductIcerik> productsL = new ArrayList<ProductIcerik>();
            try


            {
                 url = new URL("http://www.sucukevim.com/external_services.php?service=get_product&&id="+params[0]);
                 System.out.println(url);
            URLConnection connection;
            connection = url.openConnection();

            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                Document dom = db.parse(in);

                Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

                NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("product"); 
                                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                                    Node childNode = nl.item(i);
                                          Element eElement = (Element)childNode;

                                          productsL.add(new ProductIcerik(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("id", eElement)),"http://www.sucukevim.com/pictures/products/"+getTagValue("resim",eElement),getTagValue("ad",eElement),getTagValue("fiyat",eElement),getTagValue("kategori",eElement),getTagValue("birim",eElement),getTagValue("indirim",eElement),getTagValue("stok",eElement),getTagValue("etiket",eElement),getTagValue("detay",eElement),"http://www.sucukevim.com/pictures/products/"+getTagValue("resim",eElement)));
                                          System.out.println(getTagValue("ad",eElement));

                                          //productsL.add(new ProductData(Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("id", eElement)),getTagValue("ad", eElement),getTagValue("fiyat", eElement),getTagValue("kisaca", eElement),"http://www.sucukevim.com/pictures/products/"+getTagValue("resim", eElement),Integer.toString(i)));                 

                        }

                                return productsL;
            }
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e)
            {

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {

            }
            catch(ParserConfigurationException e){

            }
            catch(SAXException e)
            {

            }   
        return null;
    }

    public String getTagValue(String tag,Element eElement)
    {
        String retVal = "NOT FOUND";
        if (eElement != null&& eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0) != null)
        {
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getChildNodes();
            if (nlList.item(0) != null)
            {
                Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
                retVal = nValue.getTextContent();
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProductIcerik> result) {

      }

    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.product, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".Product" >

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/shoppingcart" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/sepetiniz" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/main_head_bg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/greetingsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="Merhaba Mesajı" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:textSize="8sp" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView4"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="25dp"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/uyelikBilgileriniz"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:adjustViewBounds="false"
     android:background="@null"
     android:cropToPadding="false"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/main_header" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
     android:layout_width="130dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:background="@null"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/logo_main" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/uyelikBilgileriniz"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
     android:background="@null"
     android:text="Üyelik Bilgileriniz"
     android:textSize="12sp" />

 <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="35dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/imageButton1"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
     android:background="@drawable/main_center" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txtaciklama"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Small Text"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
             android:textSize="10sp" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView5"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/main_top_bg" />

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView6"
     android:layout_width="80dp"
     android:layout_height="80dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/greetingsText"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/img_bg" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtbaslik"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="10sp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/imageView5"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtfiyat"
     android:text="Başlık"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/satinAldiklariniz"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
     android:background="@null"
     android:text="Satın Aldıklarınız"
     android:textSize="12sp" />
  <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
     android:layout_width="70dp"
     android:layout_height="70dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/txtbaslik"
     android:background="@null"
     android:scaleType="fitXY"
     android:src="@drawable/sepete_ekle" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtfiyat"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/satinAldiklariniz"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
      android:text="Fiyat"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textSize="12sp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtfiyat"
      android:layout_below="@+id/txtfiyat"
      android:text="Small Text"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textSize="6sp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
      android:text="Small Text"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textSize="6sp" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtstok"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
      android:text="Stok Durumu"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textSize="10sp" />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView7"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView6"
      android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
      android:src="@drawable/iicon" />
```

> 05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.Troyateck.sucukevim/com.Troyateck.sucukevim.Product}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #134: Error
>   inflating class  05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 05-26 04:41:44.994:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 05-26 04:41:44.994:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 05-26 04:41:44.994:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1028): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #134: Error inflating class  05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   com.Troyateck.sucukevim.Product.onCreate(Product.java:50) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   ... 11 more 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 05-26 04:41:44.994:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     ... 24 more 05-26 04:41:44.994:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1028): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
>   05-26 04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):   at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:120) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:110) 05-26
>   04:41:44.994: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     ... 27 more

Answer (score 3):

According to the logcat the problem is with your line 134 or during inflation of `imageView5`. Also there's  `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` before the exception. So I guess your `main_top_bg` is a very large image file which caused this exception

Comment: Problem solved. I had 2 different imageview that named imageView5

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to action bar as you may have set custom font family, just remove it or you may be using some feature which is not available in current `sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

try to cleaning and building the project.

If it still does'nt work you can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533972/android-include-tag-invalid-layout-reference) that may be the issue