# Getting a Inflation Exception in android studios

Tags: java, android, xml

So I'm trying to make a toolbar for one of my activities, so I made the layout and tried to include it but I keep getting this exception `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: You must specify a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />` if anyone has any idea what's wrong, I would be very appreciative.

My UML for the activity is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HelpScreen">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tbar"
        android:layout="@layout/help_toolbar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="363dp"
        android:layout_height="648dp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/firstParagraph"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.868" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="4dp">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix ' You must specifiy a layout in the include tag: <include layout="@layout/layoutID" />'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894173/how-to-fix-you-must-specifiy-a-layout-in-the-include-tag-include-layout-la)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tbar"
    android:layout="@layout/help_toolbar"/>
```

Instead, you want to create:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tbar"
    layout="@layout/help_toolbar"/>
```

When specifying layouts you don't need android